# Plot 2-d data in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have data like this : 
x coordinate| y coordinate |   Z 
  0.01      |    0.15      |   1
  0.23      |    0.17      |   5
  0.28      |    0.18      |   6
   ...            ...         ...
I want to plot all of these data in 2-d such that , in each point (x,y)
we have the corresponding intensity Z which i want to be depicted with a colour . Just like the function 'image' which already exists . But i have a problem that the aforementioned function of matlab plot in a uniform manner all the points. So if i have 
`x= [0 0.01 1];` 
`y = [0 1];`
'Z = [1 1 0;0 1 1];'
Then it will plot the corresponding densities at the (0,0) (0.5,0) , (1 ,0)... So it takes the max of x and the min of x and take uniform pieces . 
I want to plot my data in specific points.
Any ideas , is there any other suitable function for this ? 
How can i construct something like that ?

Comment: Use `surf`. It shoudl work

Comment: I want to see my data in 2d.

Comment: after `surf` use `view(2)` and you will see it from above (2D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is a grid that has sligth variations on the values, but still a grid, do:

```
surf(x,y,z,'linestyle','none');
axis tight;axis off; view(2)
```

Example output with

```
z=peaks;
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:49,1:49);
x=x+rand(size(x))*0.1;
y=y+rand(size(x))*0.1;
```

[image: https://i.imgsafe.org/5bd95a03e9.png]

Comment: If you don't have grid data but you have specific points with a specific intensity (Z) what can you do ?(I mean you don't have all the points of the form : every x is making a point with all the y in a vector)

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis if you do not have x and y values, then do what I have done here as an example, as its the same case

Comment: Thank a lot it was very helpful!!!